# Google Custom Search (CSE) How to get actual image on clicking thumbnail rather than landing to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-custom-search

In this link jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/library/pure/6130833/

1. In "Image" tab when you click you land to the page that contains the image rather opening the image itself.
2. Also, I don't like to show title & description below the thumbnail.

I basally like to modify result with my own HTML and CSS while fetching the CSE API provided search result data. Is there a way to accomplish it?

The one place you can see the points I mentioned above is working is in "Google Docs" while you insert Image from "Search" tab.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you can't fix it via custom search config. Just use additional css/javascript magic to manage this.

Comment: @br3t even through if I do what you said, not sure how to fix the issue mentioned in point number one, as it's a routing issue to actual image. I have also added little more info to my question.